# How do I express the position of an object by counting from the last?

Tags: word-usage

I have some events. `a` occurred the the first and `d` occurred the last. The order is as follows

> a > b > c > d

How do I express the position of `c`. I'd like to count from the last. Is it correct to say?

> c is the **second last** event

What are the alternative words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *penultimate*.

M-W:

> [*penultimate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate): next to the last, e.g., the *penultimate* chapter of a book

Comment: @WS2 Hmmm I thought it was said _second **to** last_ ?

Comment: @walen I believe *to* and *from* both work here - at least with second. But I feel awkward saying *third to last* - seems to me it should be *third from last*, but I would welcome other input. Prepositions are an area of much Br and Am divergence.

Comment: @WS2 surely *ant**e**-penultimate*?

Comment: @WS2 in my experience in the U.S. *second to last* is much more common than *second from last*, at least in sports. After that, counting backwards, *from* seems to take over: *third from last* or *third from the last*, etc. Good observation/question on your part. How would one substantiate this? I would say *ante-penultimate* applies to any item that comes before the *penultimate* item.

Comment: antepenultimate means "last but two".

Comment: @MichaelKay Wow. I didn't know that. I'll have to look it up. It's a little counterintuitive. / Okay, I looked it up in M-W. It seems to apply to syllables in words. Does it apply more broadly?

Comment: @ChrisH Quite right. My apologies. Should be *antepenultimate*.

Comment: Of course *last but one*, *last but two* etc. is a perfectly viable alternative to *second to last*, as @MichaelKay reminds me.

Comment: @WS2 That seems Br versus Am.

Comment: @RichardKayser Do you mean that *last but two*, *last but three* is not used in America?

Comment: @WS2 Yes. I've never heard those. And I'm 65 years old.